# how to perform nightmare on every request?

Tags: node.js, express, nightmare

how to perform nightmare on every request?

The method below runs only once, from the second on, the script does not run. It is in an infinite load. What can it be?

Thank you

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    nightmare
        .goto('https://site.com.br')
        .wait(() => {
            return $('#url').text() !== ''
        })
        .evaluate(() => {

            return $('#url').text()
        })
        .end()
        .then((result) => {

            res.send(result)

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Search failed:', error);
        });   

})
```

Comment: It can be a nightmare

Comment: What do you mean it only runs once? Also, you should be calling `res.send` in your catch statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

It runs only once because you are calling `.end` on your first request which ends the instance and you won't be able to use the instance for future requests.

Remove that line and it should be absolutely fine.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    nightmare
        .goto('https://site.com.br')
        .wait(() => {
            return $('#url').text() !== ''
        })
        .evaluate(() => {

            return $('#url').text()
        })
        .end() // <-- remove this line
        .then((result) => {

            res.send(result)

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Search failed:', error);
        });   

})
```